# Count number of |

Tags: batch-file, count

I need help with a script, the script is supposed to count the number of `|` before a specific  string.

info.txt

```
text=jam|hello=123|result=ok|cow=cat|...
```

So in this example the answer should be 2 if you search for result=
Is this possible in batch?

Comment: 1. Presumably the "specific string" is "result="? 2. Does the "specific string" vary?  3. Can there be more than 1 line in info.txt?  4. If so; do you want to stop after finding 1st occurence of "specific string"; or continue?  5. Case sensitive or insensitive search?

Comment: yes, this is possible. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Sorry for not answering! Yes, and no the string does not vary. Yes there need to be more than on line in info.txt. There are one of "specific string" on each line. Insensitive. Sorry again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses a helper batch file called repl.bat: from - http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3855

If you call this code below `searchstring.bat` then you can launch it like this

`searchstring "result="`

It expects only one match per file and is case sensitive.

```
@echo off
type "file.txt" | find "%~1" | repl "(.*).%~1.*" "$1" | repl "\x7c" "\r\n" x | find /c /v ""
```

This batch file below will return a count of line number and the number itself, when the number is greater than zero, per each line in the `file.txt`

```
@echo off
if "%~1"=="" ( echo add a search term&pause&goto :EOF)
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /n "^" "file.txt" ') do (
for /f %%c in (' echo "%%b"^| find "%~1" ^| repl "(.*).%~1.*" "$1" ^| repl "\|" "\r\n" x ^| find /c /v "" ') do (
if %%c GTR 0 echo Line %%a: %%c
)
)
pause
```

Comment: Would it work if you just put a for-loop  so it loop though the whole file?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.  Loop through which file?  How many lines are in the file, and how many matches can there be in one file?  Is that the problem?

Comment: It works nicely! But is it possible to loop through maybe a hundred lines of information in a file and find one per line?

Comment: See my answer, which I edited.  It uses the same syntax to launch it.  Also, please give full details when you ask your questions in future rather than asking to change the answer - as it often involves more work and extra testing.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
SET "string=text=jam|hello=123|result=ok|cow=cat|..."
SET "stop=result=ok"
SET "char=|"

SET /a count=-1
SET "org=%string%"
:loop
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=%char%" %%a IN ("%string%") DO SET "this=%%a"&SET "that=%%b"
IF DEFINED that (SET "string=%that%") ELSE (SET "string=%this%")
SET /a count+=1
IF NOT DEFINED string (ECHO NOT found: "%stop%" &GOTO :EOF)
IF NOT "%this%"=="%stop%" GOTO :loop
ECHO Number of "%char%" IN "%org%" until "%stop%": %count%
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want, eg, 3rd string:

```
SET "text=jam|hello=123|result=ok|cow=cat|..."
FOR /F "TOKENS=3" %%t IN ("%text%") DO ECHO %%t
```

If you want, eg, 3rd string and following:

```
SET "text=jam|hello=123|result=ok|cow=cat|..."
FOR /F "TOKENS=2,*" %%t IN ("%text%") DO ECHO %%u
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way (uses your info.txt file).
Case insensitive. Handles multiple lines with matching string in file.

```
@echo off
set "SpecificString=result=ok"
set /A cnt=0
for /F "tokens=*" %%A IN (info.txt) do (
   for /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%B IN (`echo."%%A" ^| find /I "%SpecificString%"`) do (
      call :Parse "%%~A"
      )
   )
pause
goto :eof

:Parse
for /F "usebackq tokens=1* delims=^|" %%B IN (`echo."%~1"`) do (
   if /I "%%~B"=="%SpecificString%" (
      echo.Cnt=%Cnt% in "%%A"
      echo.
      set /A Cnt=0
      goto :eof
      )
   set /A Cnt+=1
   call :Parse "%%~C
   )
goto :eof
```